# delete * from table not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete **all rows** from table but it isn't working. when I do `echo $mydb->error;`
it gives me the below:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM messages where from_user = ? and id = ?'`

```
     $user = 'currentuser';
 if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
 if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
 $id =  $_POST['id']; 


 $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
 $stmt = $mydb->prepare("DELETE * FROM messages where from_user = ?  and id = ? ");
 echo $mydb->error;
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $id);
 foreach  ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
$stmt->execute();
}
echo"The Message deleted permanently";
}
}
```

Comment: `DELETE *` isn't valid.  You simply want `DELETE FROM...`

Comment: You can remove the `*` and the `FROM`

Answer (score 7):

It should be

```
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("DELETE FROM messages WHERE from_user = ?  AND id = ? ");
```

And I will appreciate for using `mysqli_*` functions instead of deprecated `mysql_*`

Plus, there should not be a `*` for DELETE; that is not the right syntax.

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

The `*` syntax is used in conjunction with SELECT:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: oh I though `*` was suppossed to mean all. Thanks it works.

Comment: @MikelMax It is used to select and not to delete :)

Comment: yes @Mr.Alien you are right.It will be like `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: I made an edit to the answer in order to outline the proper syntax. Plus, this Q&A came about when searching for a duplicate in this question posted today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636973/unable-to-delete-from-database-using-php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all messages of the user:

```
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("DELETE FROM messages where from_user = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you want to delete **all rows** (be careful!) from the table:

```
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("DELETE FROM messages");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: for deleting all rows, truncate is much faster on larger size tables

Comment: @Dagon Yes, truncate is faster, but may have some issues with triggers and constraints.