# Unable to delete from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete entries from a mysql database by using a php file and for some reason it doesn't work. The connection (in "connect.php") works, as I am using the same file for my SELECT statements and those work. I am only having trouble with deleting them. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
include "include/connect.php";

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysql_connect_error());
}

$word = (isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : null);

$sql = "DELETE * from tbl_sbs WHERE eml='" . word . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: yowza!!! remove the `*` then delete the question. `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` would have signaled the syntax error

Comment: I felt like answering but that won't be appreciated anymore *sigh

Comment: Plus, error reporting would have thrown you an undefined constant word notice; **IF** that wasn't a typo.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, that was a typo when I edited this post.

Comment: that is why I wrote "if" ;-)

Comment: not to mention that you're so open to an SQL injection; it's not funny. I'm surprised nobody mentioned that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It will only be used on a private closed network

Comment: I once trusted someone whom I thought was a very good friend and many years ago. Lesson.moral of this story: Never let your guard down. Even your own Mom/Dad could (accidentally/unknowingly) send you a virus ;-) Edit: Think about "Anonymous". They even hacked our own government network and that too is a "closed private network".

Comment: @Fred-ii-, WTH, *Even your own Mom/Dad could (accidentally/unknowingly) send you a virus* ... that's funny statement. BTW, thanks for the edit in my answer. Really appreciate that.

Comment: @Rahul You're welcome Rahul. Yeah... the OP thinks just because they've a closed private network that they're completely shut out from the outside world. Not the case with our own Canadian government and.... get ready for it........ SONY. ;-) shall I go on? lol

Comment: @Rahul addendum to the above *"Even your own Mom/Dad could (accidentally/unknowingly) send you a virus"* - Taken from a real world problem once; not myself but someone I once knew. Good thing I was there to intervene and say *"No, don't open this..."*. ;-) which I was right about. We called the father to let him know about it. Even he didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `*` or column name for `DELETE` statement unless in `WHERE` clause for filtering purpose same as in `SELECT` statement. It should just be

```
$sql = "DELETE from tbl_sbs";
```

`DELETE` general syntax is

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME <comparison_operator> SOME_FILTER_CONDITION
```

So, in your case it should just be

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_sbs WHERE eml='" . $word . "'";
```

Error reporting would have thrown you an undefined constant word notice; **IF** that wasn't a typo in `'" . word . "'`.

The `*` and having checked for errors, would have thrown you the following:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: I edited my code to include a condition in the delete statement. Is the " * " needed in this case?

Comment: No, just add the `WHERE` @IrinaAvram

Comment: @IrinaAvram, NO. NEVER. See edit in answer again.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer in 8 more minutes!

Comment: Another quick question as I am unable to test at the moment, do I need to commit the changes?

Comment: *"in WHERE clause for filtering purpose"* - such as SELECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Yes, mentioned that in answer for clearing any confusion.

Comment: @Rahul do I have to commit the changes?

Comment: @IrinaAvram, Not that necessary since DML like insert/update/delete does implicit commit if it succedes but if you are taking care of it manually using a transaction block then you will have do a separate commit/rollback.

Answer (score 1):

And you must use the $ before a variable name (word)

```
$sql = "DELETE from tbl_sbs WHERE eml='" . $word . "'";
```

Comment: And you must check the *full* syntax of a `DELETE` statement.

Comment: OP said it was a typo, but you did answer what they posted originally.

Comment: *"And you must use the $ before a variable name (word)"* - Otherwise it's treated as a constant.